# rotate the camera around an object in spherical coordinates glulookat

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

so i'm trying to rotate the camera around a cube object , using the keyboard arrows to change the y angle and the x angle , i want a result like this : [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rBbaXir_DuB9Kuj38A0sIU_MuNshtD0p/view?usp=sharing)

Well now I want to move the camera in a circular motion around the shape, so I used
the sphere parametric equation to determine the camera's x, y, and z coordinates on the parameter of the sphere using the x angle and the y angle , this is the equation : [sphere parametric equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrQoI.png)

For this moment, the equation is as following:

x = radius*cos(y_angle)*cos(x_angle)

y = radius*cos(y_angle)*sin(x_angle)

z = radius*sin(y_angle)

so the code will be :

```
gluLookAt(x, y, z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0); // x,y and z that we calculated above
```

Now it is supposed to work without problems, but the camera dose rotate in a strange way that is not as it should, I think this has something to do with the **up vector** in the
glulookat() function because i'm using a constant up vector like
(0,1,0)

Anyway, I can't calculate the up vector correctly, so I want help in making a circular motion around the cube like the one that appeared in the video using the glulookat , i hope i made it clear ، Because as you have noticed, I can't explain well

Comment: Without seeing your parameters to gluLookAt, it's a bit difficult to know what the problem is. However, if you're passing in a constant vector (like [0,1,0]) as the up vector, you'll run into a singularity at the poles of the sphere since the up vector will be (anti)parallel to your look vector.

Comment: Yes, this is my exact problem, iam using a constant up vector  , I can not calculate the up vector in the correct format

Comment: @jh100 i have updated the question to make it more clear as well